# How to send pro-active message to all teams users using botbuilder v4 nodejs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am able to send the pro-active messages using v3

```
const address =
{
    channelId: 'msteams',
    user: { id: '29:1smZ9yn-ggTRUgd2ytQzb7PeTwmMBJs-WVlm3sXGwgjklvxycg' },
    channelData: {
        tenant: {
            id: ''
        }
    },
    bot:
    {
        id: '',
        name: ''
    },
    serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/',
    useAuth: true
}

var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
bot.send(msg);
```

But I want to send the pro-active messages using v4.I have a accessToken which I got from Oauth 2.0 (code-grant). In the docs everywhere it is mentioned to save the turnContext.activity when user messages bot and use it for future reference. But I want to send message to user even before he messages the bot. What I am trying to do is install bot to users teams (like slack apps) using oauth and ask questions to users.

Comment: User needs to install the app for the bot to send a proactive message. Please go through this sample in v4 to send [proactive messages in NodeJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=javascript#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_javascript).

Comment: I have already installed the bot to my microsoft teams and able to send messages usign v3.0. But I want to achieve this with v4.0. The link you provided was the same I have implemented with v3.0.

Comment: My apologies for the wrong link. Here is the sample in v4 to send [proactive messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages). Please try this out and let us know if you face any issues

Comment: Yes. that worked perfectly. I have one problem. I have a website with 10 user accounts. I will ask them to install my teams bot. When some one installs my bot My server will get notified about that ( to my messaging end point). But How can I know which particular user has installed  the bot. Is there anything like installing bots to teams account using Oauth like we do for slack bots. Can you please provide your suggestion for this problem that I am facing

Comment: Answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242876/how-to-install-a-bot-to-microsoft-teams-nodejs/61244793?noredirect=1#comment108347670_61244793