# How to install a bot to microsoft teams (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Recently I have created a bot for microsoft teams. I have installed it to my teams successfully.But is there any way where all my organization users can install app by clicking on a single link that is displayed in my web page. For example like (authenticating slack bots, similarly like google auth). and I need to store the teams details of every user so that my bot can send messages to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give a link to install the app inside teams from an external webpage, you could do that using Deeplink to app installation. Here's the format of the link https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/YourAppId. You could also add the app to your tenant app catalaog(Your organisational store) and all the members of your organisation can install the app from there.

Comment: But how can I know that which particular user has installed the app. Consider a case I have 10 users in my database. I prompted them to install my app. In return I need some thing like access_token right to message to users as a bot who has installed it in their teams account.

Comment: When a user installs the app, your bot gets a [conversationUpdate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#conversation-update-events) with the details of that user. You can use those details to send out a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) to the user.

Comment: I have one probelm here How can I know that the conversationupdate belongs to this particular user in my db? and If an owner of an Organization installs the bot I will get the details about all users in the organization right?. Can I send messages to all of them. Right now I don't have an Organization account except personal one to test. Can you please provide your suggestion on this.

Comment: @NikhilPonduri When a user installs the app, your bot will get a conversationupdate event with the details of that user, so you would know who has installed the app. No, when a owner installs the app bot does not get the details of all members in the org.